# React Native (Maybe with Expo) Audio Streaming Direct to Headphones

Tags: react-native, expo-av

I am too new for mobile app development and javascript and react native world.

For one of my customer, i need to make an app, which listens the sound from mic and stream it directly to the bluetooth headphones. I tried expo-av but i could not handle, streaming while listening.

Is there anyone to suggest me a solution?

I tried expo-av library and expected to bea able to send the sound while microphone listening, but it never happened.